# how can I call a YouTube intent from this code?

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube

How can I change this Android code to call a YouTube intent?
I want to make it fire off a YouTube Player inside my app. I think that the player that is being called is not compatible with YouTube streaming videos.

here is a code snippet below:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(DetailsOverviewRow row) {
            /* 1st row: DetailsOverviewRow */

              /* action setting*/
            SparseArrayObjectAdapter sparseArrayObjectAdapter = new SparseArrayObjectAdapter();
            sparseArrayObjectAdapter.set(0, new Action(ACTION_PLAY_VIDEO, "Play Video"));
            sparseArrayObjectAdapter.set(1, new Action(1, "Action 2", "label"));
            sparseArrayObjectAdapter.set(2, new Action(2, "Action 3", "label"));

            row.setActionsAdapter(sparseArrayObjectAdapter);

            mFwdorPresenter.setOnActionClickedListener(new OnActionClickedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onActionClicked(Action action) {
                    if (action.getId() == ACTION_PLAY_VIDEO) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PlaybackOverlayActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.movie), mSelectedMovie);
                        intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.should_start), true);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
```

UPDATE: here is the PlayerOverlay Activity code:

```
public class PlaybackOverlayActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = PlaybackOverlayActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private VideoView mVideoView;

    private LeanbackPlaybackState mPlaybackState = LeanbackPlaybackState.IDLE;

    private int mPosition = 0;
    private long mStartTimeMillis;
    private long mDuration = -1;

    /*
     * List of various states that we can be in
     */
    public enum LeanbackPlaybackState {
        PLAYING, PAUSED, IDLE
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_playback_overlay);

        loadViews();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopPlayback();
        mVideoView.suspend();
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(null);
    }

    private void loadViews() {
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        mVideoView.setFocusable(false);
        mVideoView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

        Movie movie = (Movie) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(DetailsActivity.MOVIE);
        setVideoPath(movie.getVideoUrl());

    }

    public void setVideoPath(String videoUrl) {
        setPosition(0);
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(videoUrl);
        mStartTimeMillis = 0;
        mDuration = Utils.getDuration(videoUrl);
    }

    private void stopPlayback() {
        if (mVideoView != null) {
            mVideoView.stopPlayback();
        }
    }

    private void setPosition(int position) {
        if (position > mDuration) {
            mPosition = (int) mDuration;
        } else if (position < 0) {
            mPosition = 0;
            mStartTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else {
            mPosition = position;
        }
        mStartTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.d(TAG, "position set to " + mPosition);
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return mPosition;
    }

    public void setPlaybackState(LeanbackPlaybackState playbackState) {
        this.mPlaybackState = playbackState;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_playback_overlay, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void playPause(boolean doPlay) {
        if (mPlaybackState == LeanbackPlaybackState.IDLE) {
            /* Callbacks for mVideoView */
            setupCallbacks();
        }

        if (doPlay && mPlaybackState != LeanbackPlaybackState.PLAYING) {
            mPlaybackState = LeanbackPlaybackState.PLAYING;
            if (mPosition > 0) {
                mVideoView.seekTo(mPosition);
            }
            mVideoView.start();
            mStartTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else {
            mPlaybackState = LeanbackPlaybackState.PAUSED;
            int timeElapsedSinceStart = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() - mStartTimeMillis);
            setPosition(mPosition + timeElapsedSinceStart);
            mVideoView.pause();
        }
    }

    public void fastForward() {
        if (mDuration != -1) {
            // Fast forward 10 seconds.
            setPosition(mVideoView.getCurrentPosition() + (10 * 1000));
            mVideoView.seekTo(mPosition);
        }
    }

    public void rewind() {
        // rewind 10 seconds
        setPosition(mVideoView.getCurrentPosition() - (10 * 1000));
        mVideoView.seekTo(mPosition);
    }

    private void setupCallbacks() {

        mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                mVideoView.stopPlayback();
                mPlaybackState = LeanbackPlaybackState.IDLE;
                return false;
            }
        });

        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if (mPlaybackState == LeanbackPlaybackState.PLAYING) {
                    mVideoView.start();
                }
            }
        });

        mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mPlaybackState = LeanbackPlaybackState.IDLE;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks!

ironmantis7x

Comment: Not enough code has been provided. What's in PlaybackOverlayActivity? Why a YouTube player inside your app; have you considered opening the YouTube app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use youtube api [Android](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)

-Download [Youtube API Client](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads)

-The instructions for [registering](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register) your application explain how to register your app in the Google Developers Console and to obtain an Android API key, which you will need to use the API.

-An example of code

```
public class PlayerVideo extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
public boolean FLAG_FULL=false;


public String DEV_KEY= "YOUR DEVLOPPER KEY";


    int key;
private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_trailler_play);
    Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras!=null){

        key=extras.getInt("ID");

    }

    youTubePlayerView=(YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);



    youTubePlayerView.initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY,this);
    youTubePlayerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FLAG_FULL=true;

        }
    });

}




@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.setFullscreen(FLAG_FULL);
        // loadVideo() will auto play video
        // Use cueVideo() method, if you don't want to play it automatically

        player.loadVideo(getIntent().getStringExtra("ID"));


        // Hiding player controls
        player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
    }
    //player.cueVideo(getIntent().getStringExtra("ID"));
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
    if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
        errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
    } else {
        String errorMessage = String.format(
                getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
        Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST){
        getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }
}
private YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
}
```

}

And an example of intent

```
Intent i=new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(), TraillerPlay.class);
                    i.putExtra("ID", "YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID");
                    startActivity(i);
```